# GUIMiner not detecting my GPU (AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series)?

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu-mining, guiminer

GUIMiner does not appear to be detecting my GPU. Under available devices, I am only able to see my CPU. I have an AMD Radeon 7670M GPU, that I have the most updated driver for and can confirm that it is enabled and working.

In my [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), the GPU shows up under Display Adapters and there are no errors.

Screenshot of my GUIMiner GUI, as well as the summary of my GPU from GPU-Z:

[image]

Why is this GPU not being recognized? For the record, I have been able to use GUIMiner previously using the same graphics card, but have not used it for months and since that time I have upgraded to Windows 8.1 (x64).

Answer (score 1):

The code name 'Turks' is the Fabrication process and transistors name. This means it is the GPU. There are also name such as: Cedar, Caicos, Juniper, Barts and Cayman. Don't ask me why that named them this.